# Composer uninstalls other extensions when i install a plugin

Tags: plugins, yii2, composer-php, yii2-extension

When i run following command:

```
php composer.phar require kop/yii2-scroll-pager "dev-master"
```

While installing it removes other extension.

Screenshot:

[image]

here is the complete Composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
"description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
"keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
"homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.6",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
    "kop/yii2-scroll-pager": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800
},
"extra": {
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
}
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to install extension/plugin without uninstalling other plugins/extension.
Any thoughts!

Comment: The screenshot makes it difficult to read what is happening.  Can you post a gist of your `composer.json`, `composer.lock`, and the command output with the `-vvv` flag?

Comment: @SteveBuzonas i have added `composer.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid uninstallation of other extensions just do following steps.

1) `"kop/yii2-scroll-pager": "dev-master"`

to the require section of your composer.json file.

2) `php composer.phar update`

run this command in Cmd.

by Doing this you will get all extensions latest versions as well as yii2-scroll-pager will be downloaded.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows an error message:

```
Content-Length mismatch
http://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache...
```

This means Composer has no complete information about all packages, and anything might happen then.

Make sure you have a working online connection, and try again.